# Zend router default controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I made a regex route to route any segment to category except 2 values (home or about).
Now the problem I have is that when a user browses to my base url it also routes to category.

I've looked around and I can't find a way to add an exception to my regex so that the homepage routes to index instead of category controller.

This is my code

```
<archive type="Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex">

    <route>(^(?!home$|about$).*$)</route>

    <defaults>
        <controller>category</controller>
        <action>index</action>
    </defaults>

    <reverse>%s</reverse>

</archive>`
```

if I add index or default to my exceptions it still routes to category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a static route that maps empty url to your index controller and action.

```
<home type="Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static">

    <route></route>

    <defaults>
        <controller>index</controller>
        <action>index</action>
    </defaults>

</home>
```

Comment: what if we have 10 static routes? do we need to add rule for each of them separately?

Comment: It sounds like the OP question was pretty specific. Each of the static urls mapped to the same controller/action, so adding an empty route to match/map all others was quick and easy. If all your other static urls need to map to specific controllers, then you would add individual static routes for each of them (or simply fall back to the :controller/:action url format and let the default routes handle it).